# consulta entre dos fechas con hora

Tags: postgresql

Estoy viendo como hacer una consulta en postgres en la cual pueda aplicar un between en algo como:

Viernes : 17:00Hrs / Domingo: 20:00 Hrs

Esto para cada semana

Si me pueden ayudar se los agradeceria.

Saludos!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que vayas a la [documetación de PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) y leas sobre la funcion `EXTRACT`, con ella puedes obtener varios datos de las fechas y asi poder aplicar tu filtro, sobre todo mira las opciones `dow, hour y minute`